# Mongodb MMS API Key

Tags: mongodb

Trying to get into my MMS account and I need the API key in order to reset my 2 factor authentication. All docs that I read point to the config file in /etc/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.config, but the API key section in this file is empty. I know that this server is configured correctly because I get email alerts when it goes down, but I can't recall how I inserted the API key on this server. Is there another file that could contain this key? Running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve APIKey from the `/etc/mongodb-mms/automation-agent.config` file of the `mongodb-mms-automation-agent` and for more information you can refer [automation-config-file](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/install-automation-agent-with-deb-package/#edit-the-automation-agent-config-file) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't have such a config file in that directory. Only the monitoring-agent.config file.